# Enforce Return Type in Function

Tags: r, prototype, enforcement, r6

Using R6, I would like to enforce that a method returns a particular data-type, Is this possible?

For Instance, consider the following:

```
A = R6::R6Class("ClassA",
    public=list(
       getx = function() as.integer(1)
    )
)
B = R6::R6Class("ClassB",inherit=A,
    public = list(
       getx = function() "ABCDEF"
    )
)
```

If I wanted to enforce the function `getx()` to return an integer, an instance of A is fine, but I want to prevent a subclass from returning a different type, such as the case for B. In other words, I want a function to have consistency in what it returns, regardless of where it is actually implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a workaround. Directly it is not possible, indirectly using a second function, it is.

When you define the new "getx" function in "ClassB", this completely hides the function "getx" from Class A. There is no mechanism in R6 to ensure that any return value has to pass through a particular function.

Now - what you can do is the following:

Let getx from ClassA be the public function. All it does is call a private function p_getx that actually returns the value and getx just coerces it to the right type.

Then any user implementing a ClassB inheriting from ClassA would leave the public function getx unchanged and instead implement the private method p_getx. This is the model the 'clone' method uses w.r.t. private 'deep_clone' methods.

Some example code

```
ClassA <- R6Class("ClassA",
                  public=list(
                      getx = function() {
                          return(as.character(private$p_getx()))
                      }
                      ),
                  private=list(
                      p_getx = function() {
                          return("ClassA")
                      }

                      )
                  )


ClassB <- R6Class("ClassB", inherit = ClassA,
                  private=list(
                      p_getx = function() {
                          return(factor("ClassB"))
                      }

                      )
                  )



obj_A <- ClassA$new()

obj_B <- ClassB$new()
```

with output

```
> obj_A$getx()
[1] "ClassA"
> class(obj_A$getx())
[1] "character"
> obj_B$getx()
[1] "ClassB"
> class(obj_B$getx())
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thought the solution would be something like this, however, unfortunately a user can still override the public function. It would be good if R6 had some 'hooks' so that a 'checker' function could be called every time the public function gets called. Not sure exactly how this could be implemented, or even if it possible.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton I don't quite understand why you really need these "checker" functions. The functionality of your classes could only be changed by someone else implementing a derived class of your class. And there it is as with everything else in R - it is assumed that we are grown-ups and people can override and change things as they see fit. What you could do is provide a "checker" function that someone could apply to a class to see if it follows your specifications. But I don't quite understand why you need this level of lock-down. In that case, R may simply be the wrong language for you.

Comment: thanks I appreciate your comment, I have a deep and complex inheritance tree for a project I am working on, ultimately involving a number of dynamic documents which depend on the output of a function within each R6 object (the contents of which almost every time are different, but need to return the same structure) in order to execute without error. It doesn't matter, I can get around this by returning an R6 or Structure object which has a constructor that enforces the provision of the required elements.